Macro code to change Power Query Data Source
I created a Power Query for my operators to analyze a set of data.
For this purpose, they will need to change the new data source from a selected folder.
I need VBA codes for macros that will edit the query and open to the folder source browser

To get a filename with VBA and use in PowerQuery
1 Create a named range, here aaa
2 Use VBA to populate it using a file prompt
Sub prompt()
Dim FName As Variant
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Data file (*.xl*),*.xl*", 1)
If FName = False Then
MsgBox "False"
Exit Sub
End If
Range("aaa").Value = FName
End Sub

3 Refer to the named range in powerquery you set up
let
NameValue= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="aaa"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents(NameValue), null, null, 1252)}),

To get a directory with VBA and use in PowerQuery
1 Create a named range, here aaa
2 Use VBA to populate it using a file prompt
 Sub SelectFolder()
 Dim fldr As FileDialog
 Dim sItem As String
 Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
Range("aaa").Value = sItem
End Sub

3 Refer to the named range in powerquery you set up
let NameValue= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="aaa"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Folder.Files(NameValue)
in Source

